# Chrome OS on Linux through QEMU

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, kvm, qemu

Is it possible to install full Chrome OS through KVM on Linux and where can I get the full `.iso` file or the img of Chrome OS?

Comment: Please don't use CAPS LOCK for your title. That's "internet speech" for "shouting loudly", and I don't think you're doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to install full chrome os through kvm on linux ?

Yes. Its a Linux with an android-style userland and a chrome-heavy UI.

> and where can I get the full .iso file or the img of chrome os?

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/cros_vm.md contains all the steps you need to do.

Google doesn't distribute chrome OS images as for end-users, but it does offer them for purposes of developing for that platform; so the easiest way to get them is to

0. get the depot tools
1. [Clone the Chromium git repository](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Get-the-code) (achtung: hefty),
2. [set up the simple chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/simple_chrome_workflow.md#Getting-started)
3. [run the chrome-sdk "download-vm" command: `cros chrome-sdk --board=amd64-generic --download-vm --clear-sdk-cache --log-level=info`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/cros_vm.md)

Sorry, don't have an easier way. But you#re also probably asking this because you want to develop for chromium/chrome OS, so these steps are necessary, anyways.

If you want a PC-friendly user-friendly distribution, *raw chrome OS* is not what you want, anyways; you want some distribution of it that's useful for end-users. I think the most famous one of these is "[CloudReady](https://cloudreadykb.neverware.com/s/)", but I've never tested it. They distribute an [OVA file](https://cloudreadykb.neverware.com/s/article/Download-CloudReady-Image-For-VMware), and although they claim that's for VMWare, OVA is a standardized format and can be imported into `virsh`/libvirt/kvm virtualization using [`virt-c2v`](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/importing-vms-kvm-virt-v2v).

Comment: "How do I create a ChromeOS Flex USB installer on Linux?" explains how to "Download the installation image from CrOS Updates Serving" but not how to convert their .bin to an .iso or similar that works with kvm/qemu/virt-manager//virtualbox//vmware
https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11543105?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-do-i-create-a-chromeos-flex-usb-installer-on-linux